# Unable to run an android app at a real device due to gradle being outdated

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I updated gradle at Ubuntu 13

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gradle
```

**build.gradle** at MyApplicationProject/MyApplication:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run a project at my cell phone connected to USB. But it says:

```
Uploading file
 local path: /home/alex/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplicationProject/MyApplication/build/classes/debug/MyApplication.apk
 remote path: /data/local/tmp/com2.example.myapplication
Local path doesn't exist.

Unexpected Error
           Local path doesn't exist.
           Local path doesn't exist.
           The project may need to be synced with Gradle files.
```

I do `Tool-> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files` and get an error:

It says:

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project 'MyApplicationProject': You are using an old, unsupported version of Gradle. Please use version 1.8 or greater. Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your gradle version number in the script. Change the classpath from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
```

to something like

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
```

or a different version number depending on what you have installed

Comment: In the root of your project run the command ./gradlew -v it will print the gradle version that you are using. Check that version. If it is a newer one, try ./gradlew --refresh

Comment: it's 1.6. but refresh says `No argument was provided for command-line option '--refresh'`

Comment: same thing: when I delete apk and hit "Run" Android Studio doesn't launch "gradle build", thus can't find APK. How to fix that?